# Strong type guarantees with useFormState

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms, next.js

I use React's `useFormState` hook with NextJS pretty much as described in [the official documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions-and-mutations) and in [the example project](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/next-forms/app):

```
"use client";

import { serverFunction } from "@/app/actions";
import { useFormState, useFormStatus } from "react-dom";

const initialState = "";

function SubmitButton() {
  const { pending } = useFormStatus();

  return (
    <button type="submit" aria-disabled={pending}>
      Add
    </button>
  );
}


export default function Example() {
  const [state, formAction] = useFormState(serverFunction, initialState);

  return (
    <div>
      <form action={formAction}>
        <input type="file" name="image" />
        <SubmitButton />
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(state, null, 2)}</pre>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And in `actions.ts` I have:

```
"use server";

export async function serverFunction(_: unknown, formData: FormData) {
  const imgFile = formData.get("image");
  // ... some processing
}
```

However, this approach doesn't use **static type checking** to ensure that data provided by the form on the client corresponds with what server expects. How can I introduce it in this toy example?

(Of course, I can use a library like `fp-ts` or `zod` for **runtime validation**, but that's not what this question is about).

Comment: There is an open issue https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43797 with various workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

`useFormState`, and `<form action={}>` are built on `FormData` which does not take a generic type argument. So you're out of luck.

If you want static typing and you're open to something similar, you could use a regular server action:

page.tsx

```js
'use client';

import { useState } from 'react';
import { createUser } from './user';

const initialState = {
  email: '',
  message: '',
};

export default function Signup() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);

  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={(event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        void createUser(state).then(setState);
      }}
    >
      <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="email"
        required
        value={state.email}
        onChange={(event) => setState({ ...state, email: event.target.value })}
      />

      {state.message && <p>{state.message}</p>}

      <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

user.ts

```js
'use server';

export type UserFormInput = {
  email: string;
};

export async function createUser(input: UserFormInput) {
  if (!input.email.includes('@')) {
    return {
      ...input,
      message: 'Invalid email address',
    };
  }

  return {
    ...input,
    message: 'User created',
  };
}
```

See a working example at https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-78124489